# PHP DOMDocument / XPath: Get HTML-text and surrounded tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, tags, domdocument

I am looking for this functionality:

Given is this html-Page:

```
<body>
 <h1>Hello,
  <b>world!</b>
 </h1>
</body>
```

I want to get an array that only contains the DISTINCT text elements 
(no duplicates) and an array of the tags that surround the text elements:

The result to the above "html" would be an array that looks like this:

```
array => 
 "Hello," surrounded by => "h1" and "body"
 "world!" surrounded by => "b", "h1" and "body"
```

I alreday do this:

```
$res=$xpath->query("//body//*/text()");
```

which gives me the distinct text-contents but that omits the html-tags.

When I just do this:

```
$res=$xpath->query("//body//*");
```

I get duplicate texts, one for each tag-constellation: e.g.: "world!" would show up 3 times,
one time for "body", one time for "h1" and one time for "b" but I don't seem to be able to
get the information which texts are acutally duplicates. Just checking for duplicate text is
not sufficient, as duplicate texts are sometimes just substrings of former texts or a website
could contain real duplicate text which would then be discarded which is wrong.

How could I solve this issue?

Thank you very much!!

Thomas

Comment: I think that you need xquery for this. Anyway use an XML technology on HTML isn't good. The html can be not well-formed and, thus, you'll get parsing error.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa DOM can parse broken HTML

Comment: You did not accept an answer yet. Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer and why the given answers do not satisfy you.

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over the [parentNodes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode) of the [DOMText](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php) nodes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = array();
foreach($xpath->query('/html/body//text()') as $i => $textNode) {
    $textNodes[$i] = array(
        'text' => $textNode->nodeValue,
        'parents' => array()
    );
    for (
        $currentNode = $textNode->parentNode;
        $currentNode->parentNode;
        $currentNode = $currentNode->parentNode
    ) {
        $textNodes[$i]['parents'][] = $currentNode->nodeName;
    }
}
print_r($textNodes);
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/ol85VgOV)

Note that `loadHTML` will add implied elements, e.g. it will add html and head elements which you will have to take into account when using XPath. Also note that any whitespace used for formatting is considered a DOMText so you will likely get more elements than you expect. If you only want to query for non-empty DOMText nodes use

```
/html/body//text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/GgT2tWos)

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code, `$res=$xpath->query("//body//*/text()")` is a `DOMNodeList` of `DOMText` nodes. For each `DOMText`, you can access the containing element via the `parentNode` property.

Comment: Ah, good idea, I just tried it and indeed I can access the parentNode, so I could manually iterate over all "higher" nodes to get the surrounding tags. The only drawback could be the performance. Maybe there is also another approach that does it in just one run and therefore maybe more efficient. But nevertheless, a good idea from you and I want to thank you for that and will test it now to see its performance.