# Get div's HTML content via xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I need a support on the following issue, I have a website where I want to get a product descriptions via xpath. Below the example html of the content:

```
<div id="description">
 <span>some test</span>
 <img src="some src">
 <p>
  some content etc.
 </p>
</div>
```

and now I use the below code:

```
$result = $xpath->query('//div[@id="description"]');
```

but when I'm outputting the result with the below line:

```
echo "<pre>".$result->item( 0 )->nodeValue."</pre>"; // there is always only one element
```

what I get is only unformatted: **"some testsome content etc."** with no spaces and other tags. I know it is because xpath treats all the other tags as nodes but...

I there a way to get the div's content as HTML ?

Comment: you can try var_dump($result->item(0)->ownerDocument->saveXML($result));

Comment: You might be looking for: [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087103/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I did something similar a while back and this post helped me:

[PHP DOMDocument / XPath: Get HTML-text and surrounded tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875106/php-domdocument-xpath-get-html-text-and-surrounded-tags)

It is a bit of overhead in your code, I mean if you thought (like me) it could be solved in one line with a different XPath query or something...

Hope it helped

Comment: Well, I guess there is no simple way out than that You've shown.

Answer (score 0):

DOM Document is SLOOOOOW

Why cant you do this with a regular expression?

i would do this:

// put everything on one line
$content = preg_replace("!\r\n!", "", $content);

preg_match("!(.*?)!", $content, $matches);

the above will search for  and then takes everything up until the first

Based on the HTMl above this will work.  but not if you have other  tags within the HTML

Comment: Well... yea, that came on my mind a little bit later and You are right - that is a better way to solve this problem - easier and faster.