# fn:string function for web content

Tags: php, xpath, xquery

I want to scrap webpage's content, which I already did, But my problem is, I can't get accurate link text, if there is any child tag in the link text. For example, my xquery is `"//div[@class='someclass']/div/a/text()"`, then it gets accurate result if link is somethings like this `<a href='somelink'> this is link </a>`, (my output is :: **this is link**)  but if the link is : `<a href='somelink'> this is <br /> another text </a>`, then my output is **this is**, **another text** because of child tag **br**, Then I google, then may be got some solution, my solution may be **fn:string()**, but I can't figure out how can I use **fn:string()** in **xquery/xpath** in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't show your html code. So I guess your html code is looking like this :

```
<div class='someclass'>
   <div class='otherclass'>
      <a href='somelink'> some text including child element <a>
   </div> 
</div>
```

you can try as like as given below ::

```
//div[@class='someclass']/div/*
```

It will give you all information inside **otherclass div**, Now if you tried as like as given below, may be your problem is being solved:

```
<?php
   $linkQuery     =  $xpath->query("//div[@class='someclass']/div/*");

   $linkText = array();       

   for($i=0, $len = ($linkQuery->length) ? $linkQuery->length : -1; $i < $len; $i++ )  {
      $linkText[]  = ( $linkQuery->item($i) != NULL ) ? preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $linkQuery->item($i)->nodeValue )  : 'some default text'; 
   } 
?>
```

Now you get all text inside your link text.

Answer (score 1):

`text()` selects all text nodes directly below a certain element. For `<a href='somelink'> this is <br /> another text </a>`, these are two elements, in case of `<a href='somelink'> this is <strong>another</strong> text </a>` will even omit the word `another`, as it isn't a direct child of the anchor tag.

If querying a single anchor tag within one XPath expression, use the `string($element)` function without any `text()` matcher, eg.

```
string(//div[@class='someclass']/div/a)
```

If your expression returns a sequence (in PHP: list/array) of results, loop over the results and for each anchor tag run the XPath expression `string(.)` (with `.` being the current context). For more control, you might want to use `.//text()` to fetch all text nodes below the current context, and concatenate them in PHP. [There's another answer explaining this in detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875554/695343)

Be aware PHP only supports XPath 1.0 – no XQuery, and no XPath 2.0.